# How do I pass and use a variable from app.js to index.ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Why passing variables from app.js to index.ejs in the ways I tried below does not work and how do I correctly do it? I am using Mongoose and EJS and trying to write the data in the database on the web-page instead of in the run prompt using `console.log()`.

1. (app.js snippet followed by index.ejs snippet)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){

  Review.find(function (err, doc) { // doc is an array
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    var docOne = doc[0]; // saving data of db in variable
    res.render('index', {title: "Website"}, {docOne: docOne});
  })
});
```

```
<p>Name: <%= docOne %> </p>
```

2. (app.js snippet followed by index.ejs snippet)

```
doc = Review.findOne();

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){

  Review.find(function (err, doc) { // doc is an array
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    res.render('index', {title: "Website"});
  })
});
```

```
<p>Name: <%= doc %> </p>
```

For case (1) I get an error after refreshing the page saying `docOne is not defined` and in case (2) with the global variable instead of showing all the contents of the collection I get `Name: [object Object]`. I did verify that the collection had information by using `console.log(doc)` after rendering.

There were some related posts and fixes I tried (which sum up to the ones shown above) but none of them was successful.

Comment: well your not passing it, should be `res.render('index', {title: "Website", docOne});`

Comment: Thank you. I thought I need to pass it within new curly brackets (really new to this).

Answer (score 0):

Just like the comment suggests. I was passing erroneously, should be passed with `res.render('index', {title: "Website", docOne});`